# extracting indented data from a textfile following a certain character

Tags: python, loops, parsing

Context:
I have created a text-file I with to read some data on isotopes and their relative abundance. 
I aim to use this file to extract mass and abundance for a given element.

A snippet of my text-file is shown here:

```
001
H
2
  1-0.99972
  2-0.00028
002
He
2
  3-0.0
  4-1.0
003
Li
2
  6-0.078
  7-0.922
004
Be
1
  9-1.0
005
B
2
  10-0.204
  11-0.796
```

For a given element, it will show the atomic mass, the next line the symbol, the next, x number of naturally occurring isotopes. The following x number of lines show the mass-abundance of the isotopes. These are indented by 2 spaces. Following this the next element is shown.

I am trying to write a function which takes in the symbol and outputs two lists for the mass and abundance. The following code is where I'm currently at:

```
def abundance_info(symbol):
    with open('/home/alletro/pytalys/talys_module/abundance', 'r') as abundance:
        prev_line:str = ''
        pro_prev_line: str = ''
        mass_list = [] 
        abundance_list = []
        for line in abundance:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            if pro_prev_line == symbol:
                if line[0] == ' ': 
                    print(line)
                    line.split('-')
                    mass_list.append(line[0].lstrip('\s'))
                    abundance_list.append(line[1])
                break
            else: 
                pro_prev_line = prev_line
                prev_line = line
    return mass_list, abundance_list
```

I'm however struggling with finding out how to finish this. My issue comes at the second if statement. I am struggling to find a way to iterate over the following lines which contain an indent.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the file is straight forward:

1. Loop over it, the first line is the atomic mass
2. Read the next line, it is the symbol
3. Read the next line, it is the count of how many isotopes
4. Loop to read and parse the isotopes
5. If the symbol is what we want, return
6. If we exhaust the file, that means symbol not found, return two empty lists

```py
def lookup(symbol: str) -> tuple:
    with open('abundance.txt') as stream:
        for atomic_mass in stream:
            symbol_in_file = next(stream).rstrip()
            isotopes_count = int(next(stream))  # Read the next line, convert to int

            mass_list = []
            abundance_list = []
            for _ in range(isotopes_count):
                mass, abundance = next(stream).strip().split("-")
                mass_list.append(int(mass))
                abundance_list.append(float(abundance))

            if symbol_in_file == symbol:
                return mass_list, abundance_list

    # Gets here means the symbol is not found in the file
    return [], []


def main():
    for symbol in ["H", "He", "Li", "Be", "B", "Bebop"]:
        mass_list, abundance_list = lookup(symbol)
        print()
        print("Symbol:", symbol)
        print("Mass List:", mass_list)
        print("Abundance List:", abundance_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Symbol: H
Mass List: [1, 2]
Abundance List: [0.99972, 0.00028]

Symbol: He
Mass List: [3, 4]
Abundance List: [0.0, 1.0]

Symbol: Li
Mass List: [6, 7]
Abundance List: [0.078, 0.922]

Symbol: Be
Mass List: [9]
Abundance List: [1.0]

Symbol: B
Mass List: [10, 11]
Abundance List: [0.204, 0.796]

Symbol: Bebop
Mass List: []
Abundance List: []
```

**Notes**

- The call `next(stream)` will read and return the next line in the file. We can mix it with the for loop
- I purposely add a symbol that is not found in the file (Bebop) to test the symbol-not-found case
- My code also convert the mass to integers and the abundance to floating points

Answer (score 0):

The inclusion of a continue statement will allow the code to go back to the first loop and repeat with a following line of code. An else statement breaks when the indentation stops, signalling the final isotope.

```
def abundance_info(symbol):
with open('/home/alletro/pytalys/talys_module/abundance', 'r') as abundance:
    prev_line:str = ''
    pro_prev_line: str = ''
    mass_list = [] 
    abundance_list = []
    for line in abundance:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if pro_prev_line == symbol:
            if line[0] == ' ': 
                line = line.split('-')
                mass_list.append(line[0].lstrip('\s'))
                abundance_list.append(line[1])
                continue
            else: 
                break
        else: 
            pro_prev_line = prev_line
            prev_line = line
return mass_list, abundance_list
```